# How to deal with covariant return types with SWIG for C#?

Tags: c#, c++, swig

I am currently using SWIG to generate C# bindings for a third party C++ codebase. I've mostly gotten things working, but there is one thing I'm struggling with. In the codebase, there is a "clone()" method in many of their classes which returns a copy of the calling object. The method uses covariant return types in the C++ code to return an object of the given class's type, but, due to C# not supporting covariant return types, the return types of the clone methods in the generated C# code are all that of the base class.

Is there a method within SWIG to change the return type of all "clone()" methods to match that of the class in which they reside?

I tried using typemap with

```
%typemap(cstype) *::clone "$csclassname"
```

and similar variations, but received errors when trying to generate the bindings.

The only "working" method I've found is to use

```
%ignore *::clone;
```

then use typemap(cscode) to redefine the clone method with the correct type for all classes that use it, but that is extremely tedious.

I think I just don't completely understand how SWIG typemaps work/if they can work with specific methods like this. If anyone has suggestions for a better way to do this and/or an explanation that could help clarify things for me, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Adjusted description to identify the problem as C# not supporting covariant return types.

Edit 2: To clarify, C# 9.0 supports covariant return types, but earlier versions do not. I am using an earlier version for compatibility with a Unity project. I may be able to upgrade the project and my C# version for covariant return type compatibility, though I'm not sure if SWIG's C# tool is compatible with C# 9.0. I wanted to check if there is a workable SWIG solution for my current C# and Unity versions before pursuing that potential option.

Sample Code to Reproduce Issue:

**Parent.h**

```
#ifndef PARENT_H
#define PARENT_H
class Parent
{
    public:
        int val1;
        Parent::Parent() = default;
        Parent::Parent(const Parent &copiedObject);
        virtual Parent* clone() const;
};
#endif
```

**Parent.cpp**

```
#include "Parent.h"
Parent::Parent(const Parent &copiedObject)
{
    val1 = copiedObject.val1;
}
Parent* Parent::clone() const
{
    Parent* clone = new Parent(*this);
    return clone;
}
```

**Child.h**

```
#ifndef CHILD_H
#define CHILD_H
#include "Parent.h"
class Child : public Parent
{
    public:
        int val2;
        Child::Child() = default;
        Child::Child(const Child &copiedObject);
        Child* clone() const override;
};
#endif
```

**Child.cpp**

```
#include "Child.h"
Child::Child(const Child &copiedObject) : Parent(copiedObject)
{
    val1 = copiedObject.val1;
    val2 = copiedObject.val2;
}
Child* Child::clone() const
{
    Child* clone = new Child(*this);
    return clone;
}
```

**CSharpModule.i**

```
%module CSharpModule
%{
#include "Parent.h"
#include "Child.h"
%}

%newobject *::clone;
%include "Parent.h"
%include "Child.h"
```

**clone() method in generated Child.cs**

```
public override Parent clone() {
    global::System.IntPtr cPtr = CSharpModulePINVOKE.Child_clone(swigCPtr);
    Child ret = (cPtr == global::System.IntPtr.Zero) ? null : new Child(cPtr, true);
    return ret;
}
```

Due to lack of support for covariant return types in C#, the clone() method would need to change to "new" instead of "override (SWIG's %csmethodmodifiers directive) in the derived class:

**Desired clone() method**

```
public new Child clone() {
    global::System.IntPtr cPtr = CSharpModulePINVOKE.Child_clone(swigCPtr);
    Child ret = (cPtr == global::System.IntPtr.Zero) ? null : new Child(cPtr, true);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Since you tagged as C++ and C++ doesn't have reflection, how do you return an object's type?

Comment: Since you tagged with C++, there are no `typemaps` in *standard* C++, so I can't help you understand them.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews `typemap` is a SWIG directive.

Comment: Make a [mcve] with a single sample class that exhibits the behavior when wrapped.  Include all the files nececssary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've added some sample code for reproducing the issue. I did not include the CMake files I used to build the code as I figured methods of building the code are up to personal preference, but I can add them if needed.

Comment: Also, since first opening the issue, I've realized that the issue is caused by the fact that C# does not support covariant return types like C++ does. As such, I think the solution would require the methods to either (A) be typemapped (or retyped in some other way) to match the class in which they reside and changed from "override" to "new" (probably with csmethodmodifier) or (B) ignored and replaced with methods that perform the desired action and return the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you get your information, but your entire premise is wrong. C# definitely [supports covariant return types](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iVhJoc):

```
    abstract class B 
    {
        public abstract B Build();
    }
    
    class D : B
    {
        public override D Build() => new();
    }
```

That said, this feature in either language adds essentially nothing, since any "correct" OOP program will use the base class' (or interface's) methods. If you find yourself constantly down-casting to get the more specific version of the function, you should probably rethink your design.

After all, the code generated is identical with or without this feature. This is a compile-time only feature.

Comment: SWIG Warning 842: "Covariant return types not supported in C#. Proxy method will return basetype (C#)." C# 9.0 supports covariant return types, but earlier versions, which I'm using for compatibility with a Unity project, do not.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by covariant return types add nothing? In my example case, if I want to create a clone/copy of a Child object and use methods specific to the Child class with that new object, wouldn't I need the returned object to be of the Child type, not the Parent type? Yes, the enclosed code is the same, but the differing return type (without covariant return type support) is what's causing the issue for me. I can't declare an object of type Child and set it to the returned value of another child object's clone() method since that returned value is of type Parent.

Comment: "earlier versions, which I'm using for compatibility with a Unity project, do not" that is definitely not what you said in your question, you claimed C# doesn't support it. Perhaps a better way to phrase it is that Unity doesn't support it. Also, it should be blazingly obvious that it adds nothing but syntactic sugar, because *you cannot overload return types in any language*, including C# and C++. So what you have here is the same return type, just with an implicit cast if you call your function through the (static) child type.

Comment: You are correct; I did not realize that at the time of my initial post. That SWIG warning and my initial investigation into the "issue" indicated that C# simply does not support covariant return types, hence my original statement. Upon further investigation, I found that C# 9.0 supports it, so I edited the initial question to make the clarification for my particular use case.

Comment: So are you saying that the only difference between (1) returning an object of type Parent then explicitly down-casting it to type Child (what I currently have to do) and (2) returning an object of type Child (what I'd like to do) is simply whether the down-casting happens explicitly or implicitly?

Comment: Exactly. And most of the time not even that, because, like shadowing, it's done through the static interface of the child class (ie, you have to explicitly cast your parent handle to the child class to get the covariant return in the first place), thus not even gaining a cast